# C - Working with pointer to pointer has arguments in fuction

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm learning and trying to understand properly this part of working with C.

I am doing an exercise and have to write a function that returns an image but has a pointer to pointer that has to store a value in case there's a error.

FYI: The function is stored in a module that is included by the main file.

Here's a signature declaration of my code:

```
Img imageFromFile(const char * filename, char ** messageErreur) {

if (error) 
messageErreur = 1; //Trying to pass 1 has error code out of the function

}
```

And i keep on getting this message when I compile :

> ```
> img.c:148:23: attention : assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
>      messageErreur = 1; //Trying to pass 1 has error code out of the function
> ```

I don't know what i'm note to sure what i need to declare in the main file to pass along this function.

It's a pointer to a pointer so i guess I'll need to create a pointer of type char[]?

The pass the address "&pointer" when calling the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caller is providing a pointer to a char pointer, in other words, you have been granted the ability to return a char* back to the caller. To do this, first dereference the  char** and then assign the char* you want to return:

```
*messageErreur = "some string";
*messageErreur = someRuntimeAllocatedStringBuffer;
```

Always be careful that if the caller was given the pointer to "some error string" they must not modify it (and typically would not for a returned message).

Comment: So it's true, i forgot to consider that "some string" is an array of char !

Answer (score 1):

`messageErrueur` is a pointer that points to a char pointer. That char pointer will point to a string of characters which will presumably be the error message. So lets say that there is an error message declared outside of the function:

`char * error = "error message"`

Inside the imgFromFile, where you assign `messageErrueur`, you would make `messageErrueur` point to `error` like this:

`messageErrueur = &error;`

The ampersand (`&`) gives the address of `char * error` to `messageErrueur`, so now `messageErrueur` is looking at the characters being stored at `error`.

Correct me if I had any misunderstanding of the question. Hope this helps!